# "Made in USA" vs. "Made in the USA"

Tags: articles

I browsed in a drug store and found some medical products had "**Made in USA**" on their labels, and some others had "**Made in the USA**".

If both are correct and they mean the same thing, which one do you prefer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using THE before some countries](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24622/using-the-before-some-countries)

Comment: Remember, conventions for speech and formal writing do not always align with conventions for headlines and labels.

Comment: It's not a duplicate (of that question, at least). This one has to do with the abbreviated style of English sometimes used on packaging and labels. The other one has to do with conventions for including an article in the names of different countries.

Comment: I agree with @BenKovitz. The answerer would mainly emphasize on the shortening of the sentences that occur in packaging industry.

Answer (score 11):

When we have unlimited time to talk and unlimited space to write, we can say or write everything in full: 'This product was made in the United States of America'. Very often, time to talk or space to write is limited (or people expect other people to understand what they mean), so people abbreviate: 'the US of A', 'the USA', 'the US' or leave out words which can be understood in the context (and constructed if necessary): 'This product was' and, in your question, 'the'. Officially, the 'the' is necessary; unofficially, it is sometimes (and in some contexts, often) left out.

Answer (score 1):

[COMPLYING WITH THE **MADE IN USA** STANDARD](https://www.ftc.gov/tips-advice/business-center/guidance/complying-made-usa-standard)

"Made in USA" is the "official" standard when used for qualified or unqualified claims about a products manufacturing origin. The statement isn't about 'preference' but falls in line with legal requirements set out by the US Federal Trade Commission and US Customs Service.

Comment: Yes, this is right: Look on your stuff, you will see: Made in USA, Made in France, Made in India, etc. no the. I wish people would not downvote before checking. However, there is no need to capitalize all that.

Comment: @Lambie I wasn’t the downvoter, but if they voted on the first revision of this answer, it was a completely reasonable thing to do.

Answer (score -2):

"**Made in USA**" and "**Made in the USA**" are same in its meaning but has marketing strategy and significance. When a consumer sees a product is "**made in the USA**" they perceive this as higher quality and "THE" is stressing word its an assurance to customers about the complete manufacturing of the product in USA.