# The UK has approved a COVID vaccine

Tags: definite-article, proper-nouns

What does "The" emphasize in the phrase "The UK has approved a COVID vaccine"? It seems to mean that "UK has approved a COVID vaccine" is itself OK. I am not very sure.

> **The UK has approved a COVID vaccine** — here’s what scientists now want to know
> The Pfizer–BioNTech vaccine has passed safety and efficacy tests — but scientists still have many questions about how this and other vaccines will perform as they’re rolled out to millions of people.
>
> Source:  [Nature](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-020-03441-8)  Dec.3, 2020

Comment: 'The United Kingdom' is the standard way to refer to the nation (the same as 'the United States' and other nations whose official name is a phrase).

Comment: It is part of the name of the country  "The UK" but not "The Britain"  See [Using THE before some countries](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24622/using-the-before-some-countries)

Comment: Thank you. But if so, why there has never been "The China" but always "China"?

Comment: See the linked question... "The UK",  "The USA", "The Russian Federation",  "The Peoples Repubic of China"  .... but "Britain",  "America",  Russia",  "China"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on whether the name of the country is just a proper noun or a common noun/collection of common nouns.

For example:

> The United Kingdom: is a collection of common nouns
>
> The United States of America is a collection of common nouns followed by a proper noun

Whereas

> Russia: Just a proper noun
>
> China: Just a proper noun
>
> Britain: Just a proper noun