# "the Auckland" or "Auckland"

Tags: definite-article, proper-nouns

Can you please let me know which of the following sentences is correct?

1 Because of this reason **the Auckland** is having greater productivity.

2 Because of this reason **Auckland** is having greater productivity.

Comment: If you mean the New Zealand city, have you looked for any news items, etc, and studied the usage?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using THE before some countries](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24622/using-the-before-some-countries)  That applies to countries, but the same is true of other proper nouns like the names of cities (which rarely have an article as part of the name)

Comment: Off hand, I can only think of two cities in the world that use an article in their names (the Hague and Los Angeles), and one of those is because of the city name originating in a different language than has been dominant in that city for the past couple centuries.